# Contraction of indices of connection coefficients: Levi-Civita connection vs other connections

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

I am wondering in what sense the [formula of contraction of indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#Contraction_of_indices) for the connection coefficients of the Levi-Civita connection (i.e. the Christoffel symbols) is valid for other connections.

\begin{equation} \tag{1}
\Gamma ^{i}{}_{ki}={\frac {\partial \ln {\sqrt {|g|}}}{\partial x^{k}}}
\end{equation}

My questions:

Is (1) specifically valid for the Levi-Civita connection or does it also hold for other (metric) connections, maybe if they have certain properties like being torsion free?
(I learned that torsion-free is equivalent to the connection coefficients being symmetric in the lower indices, so I suspect it is crucial for (1) to hold.)

Is there a more general contraction law for other connections (maybe with certain properties), e.g. (1) extended by some additional term?